# Cannot read property 'userID' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am creating users by registering them and storing them into mongoDB. When I go to login with the users I create I am receiving the error:
Cannot read property 'userID' of undefined

I am unsure as to why I cannot login with my users I create and store their session.

```
router.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
  // Check for duplicate/active session
  console.log('req.body');
  console.log(req.body);

  if(req.session.currentUser){
    res.locals.userName = req.session.currentUser[0].firstName;
    UserDB.find({userID: req.session.currentUser.userID})
      .then(function(user){
        ItemDB.find({userID: user[0].userID})
          .then(function(userItemList){
            res.render('myItems', {userItemList: userItemList});
          })
      })

    } else {
      // Error userID undefined
      UserDB.find({userID: req.session.currentUser.userID})
        .then(function(user){
          // Validation check upon sign in
          req.check('username').not().isEmpty().equals(user[0].username);
          req.check('password').not().isEmpty().equals(user[0].password);

          var errors = req.validationErrors();

          if(errors === false){
            // Checks for an active session
            req.session.currentUser = user;
            res.locals.userName = req.session.currentUser[0].firstName;
            currentUser = req.session.currentUser[0];
            ItemDB.find({userID: user.userID})
              .then(function(userItemList){
                res.render('myitems', {userItemList: userItemList});
              })
          } else {
              res.locals.err = true;
              res.render('login');
          }
        });
  }
});

router.get('/', function(req, res){
  // Checks for an active session
  if(req.session.currentUser){
    res.locals.userName = req.session.currentUser[0].firstName;
    UserDB.find({userID: req.session.currentUser.userID})
      .then(function(user){
        ItemDB.find({userID: user[0].userID})
          .then(function(userItemList){
            res.render('myItems', {userItemList: userItemList});
          })
      })

    } else {
      res.locals.err = false;
      res.render('login');
  }
});
```

Comment: userID is mentioned a lot in this code. Exactly which line throws the error? Wherever it occurs, it means that the object from which you tried to read this property does not actually exist. So you probably need to debug a bit more and find out why that is - perhaps a record was not returned from a query as you expected? If so, then you need to find out if your query was wrong, or whether the record never existed in the first place. From the code alone, it's hard to be sure what the root cause might be.

Comment: looks like it's an array `currentUser[0]` but you're accessing like object `currentUser.userID`?

Comment: In addition to the previous comments: In your POST route you are checking `if(req.session.currentUser){` but then in the else you're using the currentUser object. That will throw this error every time the currentUser object doesn't exist.

Comment: Line 74 is where I am getting the initial error:
  UserDB.find({userID: req.session.currentUser.userID})

Comment: mark which exactly is **line 74** in your code using comments, there are multiple `UserDB.find` :)

Comment: Marked the current line

Comment: Earlier in the code, you refer to currentUser as if it's an array (e.g. `req.session.currentUser[0]`), but in the error line you're accessing it like it's an object which has properties directly (i.e. `req.session.currentUser.userID`). This seems inconsistent. Did you use the debugger to inspect the variable and see what it really contains? I can't be sure without seeing the content of the variable, but I suspect that changing it to `req.session.currentUser[0].userID` would probably be helpful. This same thing happens in several places in your sample code.

Comment: Also, there's a logic error which I think is the real root of the problem: You write `if(req.session.currentUser)... else {` . This checks whether the "currentUser" property in the session is defined or not. If it's not defined, then it goes to the else block. This means that `req.session.currentUser` doesn't exist. So why then, on the very first line of the `else` do you try to access a property of `req.session.currentUser`? You already know, from your own if statment, that it doesn't exist! So obviously the code will fail. It's unclear what you were trying to achieve, but that's the problem